# jQuery unrecognized expression with hashbang

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hashbang

I have some fragments that load on click. I also scroll the page to the top on these links, as found on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/). I get the following error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!Fragment_Name

My js

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);//this is where the error is
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
        }
    }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<li><a href="#!Fragment_Name">Link Text</a></li>
```

I have tried var target = $($(this.hash)); no joy

Everything still works, I just want to know how to fix this and remove the error from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.replace` to escape the `!` :

```
$(this.hash.replace( /([!])/g, "\\$1" ))
```

Comment: I replaced var target = $(this.hash); with var target = $(this.hash.replace( /([!])/g, "\\$1" )); The error now reads Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=!Fragment_Name]

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign That's your second selector (`$('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');`). Just add quotes after the `=` and before `]` : `$('[name="' + this.hash.slice(1) +'"]');`

Comment: Excellent! combining the two worked. I dont understand what the /[!]/g does exactly, I know it is escaping the "!" but not why. The second part I get, escaping the "#" in the slice. Thank you very much, great answer!

Answer (score -1):

This is because there is a special character in your JQuery selector. Remove the ! from your href and it will be okay.

Comment: Cannot do that, need the '!#' / hashbang so google crawls the AJAX content.